# bibliography does not apper

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using texmaker on ubuntu 12.04.   After compiling the bibliography does not apper.  I am new to latex so maybe I am doing something of wrong. 
I know that there are a lot of post with the same problem but I am not able to solve with them.

here a small example:

this is the file AWSPCA.tex

```
    \documentclass[oneside]{article}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
%%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
%% correct bad hyphenation here
%\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}



\begin{document}
Hello  \cite{shen2008sparse}


\bibliography{biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

And here the file biblio.bib

%List of References

```
@article{shen2008sparse,
  title={Sparse principal component analysis via regularized low rank matrix approximation},
  author={Shen, Haipeng and Huang, Jianhua Z},
  journal={Journal of multivariate analysis},
  volume={99},
  number={6},
  pages={1015--1034},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Academic Press}
}
```

The two files are in the same folder.

The obtained output is
 `Hello[?]` 
without the bibliography. I tried to compile the file different times.

From the compiler I receive this warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `shen2008sparse' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
No file AWSPCA.bbl.
[1
{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./AWSPCA.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Comment: I know that this question has been already asked. But I have not been able to solve my problem with the existing answer.

Comment: Did you definitly ran `bibtex`? What does the blg-file say?

Comment: compiles just fine. Just for the fun of it, did you try to delete the `.aux` file, and then rerun as latex, bibtex, latex, latex

Comment: @Johannes_B When I run bibtex I received an error but no log is showed.

Comment: @daleif I have already tried but nothing change.

Comment: Well, there definitly will be a blg, and when you can read the error, you can also post it!

Comment: Are you on windows? it has the nasty habit of not showing the file extension.

Comment: Compiling bibitex I have been able to solve on the small example. I still get an error during bibtex compiling on a much larger document. Should I open a new tread?

Comment: Now it is working alson on the big document. I did not change nothing :S